# How can I update a variable in my dockerfile based on the value of another variable?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, command-line-interface

I need to update my `JAVA_ARGS` variable before I send it to to the `java -server` command.

When a user calls `./script/server -d`, I want to append debug arguments. Here's the related part of my `./script/server`:

```
for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
    -d|--debug)
    DEBUG_ARGS="--build-arg DEBUG_MODE=true"
    shift
    ;;
    -h|--help)
    display_usage
    exit
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Unknown option"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
done

docker-compose build ${DEBUG_ARGS} app
docker-compose up
```

Here is a snippet from my `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  app:
    environment:
      ...
      JAVA_ARGS: -Xms2048m -Xmx3072m
      JAVA_ARGS_DEBUG: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5080
```

This seems to work, and I think my `dockerfile` is correctly detecting the `DEBUG_MODE=true` variable. Here's my `dockerfile`: (some things removed)

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine

ARG DEBUG_MODE=false
ENV DEBUG_MODE ${DEBUG_MODE}

ARG JAVA_ARGS=
ENV JAVA_ARGS ${JAVA_ARGS}    

RUN if [ $DEBUG_MODE == "true" ]; \
        then echo "Debug mode on."; JAVA_ARGS=$JAVA_ARGS $JAVA_ARGS_DEBUG; \
        else echo "Debug mode off."; \
    fi;

RUN echo "Echoing JAVA_ARGS: "; \
    echo "${JAVA_ARGS}";

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD java -server ${JAVA_ARGS} -jar /app/app.jar
```

I correctly see `Debug mode on.` output to the console.

But then `echo "${JAVA_ARGS}";` is blank. And, indeed, when it gets to the last line, the args are not passed to the `java` command, and debugging is not enabled.

My bash is pretty shaky, do you know why I'm not able to update and use that var in the final command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make these options configurable at run time, and not try to "bake in" settings into the Docker image.  (If the image has a 3 GB heap size hard-coded, can I run it on a system with only 1 GB of RAM?  Or 64 GB?)

Your Dockerfile hints at an ENTRYPOINT script and that's a good place to put settings like this.  We might trim the Dockerfile down to:

```sh
FROM openjdk:8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY app.jar docker-entrypoint.sh ./
ENTRYPOINT "/app/docker-entrypoint.sh"
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Then the entrypoint script can make decisions, based on command-line options or environment variables:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$JAVA_OPTS" ]; then
  JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx3072m"
fi
if [ -n "$DEBUG_MODE" ]; then
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5080"
fi
export JAVA_OPTS
exec "$@"
```

And then run it:

```
docker run --rm -p127.0.0.1:5080:5080 -e DEBUG_MODE=yes myimage
```

You'd run *the same* image "for debugging" or "for real"; you don't need to recompile it or make `docker build` time decisions about how to set variables.